# Продолжаем убивать c++ #include

Tags: include, c++

Есть файлы:

```
class1.cpp
class1.h
class2.cpp
class2.h
class3.cpp
class3.h
main.cpp
```

В main.cpp

```
#include "class1.h"
#include "class2.h"
#include "class3.h"
```

В каждом из классов используется

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

Можно ли как то избавиться от кучи инклудов каждом из классов?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Для начала учимся расставлять теги. C++ и С++ - разные теги.
2. А зачем уменьшать кол-во инклюдов? Чисто гипотетически, есть два глобальных подхода: либо делать супер-инклюд-файл, в который включать все зависимости, которые требуются для модуля или для проекта, либо в каждый из исходных файлов включать только то, что необходимо именно для этого исходного файла. Плюсы и минусы есть у каждого из способов. Например, плюсом второго способа является то, что файлы классов 1-3 получаются независимы друг от друга. Это может быть актуально в ситуации, если их нужно распространять для других разработчиков или создается некая библиотека. Первый способ хорош для маленьких проектов, которые состоят из нескольких "сильно" связанных компонентов. Касательно времени компиляции - тут не угадаешь что лучше. Может быть лучше и одно, и другое в зависимости от ситуации, тем более - от частоты обновления хидеров. Кстати, если используется один большой хидер, то при его изменении придется пересобирать все, что от него зависит. При изменении одного маленького хидера, включенного в два-три файла, будут пересобраны только лишь эти два-три файла.

Таким образом, получается, что в каждом конкретном случае программист должен для себя решить как ему удобнее строить программу. В конце-концов каких-то совсем уж жестких ограничений что и как делать нет. Ну, разве что компилятор может потребовать специальных хидер-файлов в случае использования предкомпилированных заголовков (вспоминаем msvc с его дурацким `stdafx.h`)

Comment: Большое спасибо! msvc... У меня gcc...

Comment: совсем не в тему, и вообще смахивает на занудство, но всё же - откуда пошло это слово "хидер"? Хэдер же, от слова "head"

Comment: @DreamChild наверное, потому что так на русский слух приятнее. Возможно как-то перекликается с healer = "хилер". Не знаю, короче, наверняка.

Comment: @gecube, а мне наоборот, хИдер совсем не нравится.

Comment: @avp мне хИдер тоже как-то режет слух. Хотя его появление в общем-то понятно - правила транскрипции английского языка довольно корявы и полны различных нюансов. В частности, сочетание **ea** в большинстве случаев читается именно как протяжное **и**, однако слово **head** читается как **э**, поскольку за ним следует буква **d**, что у многих людей вылетает из головы

Comment: @DreamChild, вот что странно, 30 лет все говорили хЭдер и от всех слышали тоже хЭдер, а тут оказалось, что новое поколение правила английского языка так творчески изучает.

Comment: @avp я то, что было 30 лет назад по понятным причинам не застал, однако смею предположить, что 30 лет назад круг программистов был куда более узок. А может, просто советское образование было лучше россиийского

Comment: @DreamChild, C и Unix -- это уже после института.

Answer (score 0):

Если хэдеры классов инклудятся друг в друга, то в "нижнем" по иерархии файле неявно подключаются хэдеры, используемые в "верхних" файлах, так что отдельно их можно не указывать.
Кроме того, "хороший стиль" (тм) диктует нам необходимость избавляться от инклудов в хэдерах (перенося их в файлы *.cpp), используя forward declaration, где это возможно. А возможно это в случаях, если в заголовочном файле используется указатель на класс, без обращения к его членам (и других ситуаций, в которых нужен размер объекта). Таким образом, мы можем свести к минимуму неявное включение (в каких-то случаях - избыточное). Конкретный пример:

```
//-------------
// SomeType.h
//-------------
class OtherType;

class SomeType
{
    int i_;
    OtherType* ptr_;

public:
    SomeType(int a, OtherType* pObj);
    void Action(OtherType* pObj);
};

//-------------
// SomeType.cpp
//-------------
#include "OtherType.h"

SomeType::SomeType(int a, OtherType* pObj);
    : i_(a), ptr_(pObj)
{
}
void SomeType::Action(OtherType* pObj)
{
    ...
}
```